# Where should I place my intent code for the Twitter Android Fabric SDK?

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

In the Twitter documentation for instantiating Twitter login with TwitterCore, there are two viable locations to place an intent to start an activity on success:

*In the callback directly (which requires a private instance variable mContext as the context)
*In the onActivityResult (which is in the login activity, and requires calling this as the context)

Is there a preferred method? What are the pros and cons of either one?

Android Callback v1 (from loginButton.callback declaration):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_session);
        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                Log.i("SUCCESS", twitterSessionResult.data.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

Android Callback v2 (from onActivityResult):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_session);
        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                Log.i("SUCCESS", twitterSessionResult.data.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == -1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Log.i("On activity result resultCode", String.valueOf(resultCode));
            Log.i("On activity result requestCode", String.valueOf(requestCode));
            Log.i("On activity result data", data.toString());

        }



    }
```

Comment: Have your declared twitter activity in your manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes. The code runs wherever I place the intent - the question is really about best practices.